# Capacity Scheduler

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

The Capacity Scheduler allows sharing of Hadoop cluster along organizational lines, whereby each organization is allocated a certain capacity of the overall cluster. 
I want to know that if large data come, then the capacity allocated to that to certain queue will be change automatically?

Answer (score 0):

in capacity scheduler config we define `yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.<queue name>.capacity` and `yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.<queue name>.maximum-capacity`

`yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.<queue name>.capacity` is the capacity of queue while `yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.<queue name>.maximum-capacity` is maximum resources all jobs/users in that queue can take

if large data come, then the capacity allocated to that to certain queue will be change automatically.

No, queue size is fixed and doesn't change automatically according to input data volume.
you can manually change it in `capacity-scheduler.xml` and then refresh queues by  `yarn rmadmin -refreshQueues`

you can write a script which will update (and refresh) the queues capacity according to input data volume but I don't think it is recommended.